# java -- how to make new text block appear every time a button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, settext

I'm new at Java and trying to make a simple interactive fiction game with a GUI using swing. Right now I'm trying to break a large block of text into sections so it will fit onto the screen easily. I want one block of text to show in a Jtextarea with a "continue" Jbutton on the bottom of the screen, where every time a user clicks the Jbutton the current text will disappear and be replaced with new text. Here's the relevant code:

```
    public class forwardScreenHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        mainTextArea.setText("Nice change!");
        mainTextArea.setText("do it again!");
        mainTextArea.setText("Please be third!");

            }
        }

public void chooseYes(){
    yesnoButtonPanel.setVisible(false);
    continueButtonPanel.setVisible(true);
    continueButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    continueButton.removeActionListener(contHandler);
    continueButton.addActionListener(userCont);
    position = "yes";
    mainTextArea.setText("Blah Blah Blah");

}
```

Clearly the code will result in "blah blah blah" being initially shown, then when I click the continue button the final setText "Please be third!". I understand it's because I haven't written any code telling Java to setText every time the continue button is clicked, but I can't figure out how to do this. Like I said I'm a beginner, so any explanation would be helpful so I can understand what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a variable and if statements to do this.

Declare a variable at the class level to store how many times the button has been pressed:

```
private int buttonPressCount = 0;
```

In the action listener for the continue button, first increment this variable, then set text based on the value of it.

```
buttonPressCount++;
switch (buttonPressCount) {
    case 1:
        mainTextArea.setText("Nice change!");
        break;
    case 2:
        mainTextArea.setText("do it again!");
        break;
     case 3:
        mainTextArea.setText("Please be third!");
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy! I thought I needed to use some kind of increment, but had been trying to do it inside a while loop. I didn't realize you could increment like that within an actionlistener. Thank you!